# Anchor tag from iframe to parent cross-domain/cross-browser

Tags: html, iframe, cross-domain, anchor

I'm not sure if this is even possible, but can a link that lives inside of an iFrame (on another domain) be used to access an anchor on its parent page?

For example:

Parent url: http://www.parenturl.com
Parent DIV to be targeted: `<div id="anchortag">`

iFrame url: http://www.iframeurl.com
Link inside of iframe: `<a href="http://www.parenturl.com#anchortag"></a>`

This method seems to work as expected in FF and Chrome but does not in Safari or IE. IE simply refreshed the page when the link is clicked.

Is there any documented reason as to why IE would refresh and why this approach doesn't work?